# Camera Tracking markers

Tags: camera, tracking, video

I want to do some camera tracking. The things that I will be filming does not have a lot of detail on it, so that I will have to place some extra markers here and there. I am not sure what kind if markers to make. Should I make simple X's or should I just put some dots on it?

Comment: An X is not very good. If your video has motion blur the tracking can slide along one of the strokes that make up the x.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the new affine/perspective tracking you can get much better tracking by having a marker that has some features within it. Here's a brief hierarchy of how I think about what makes a good tracking marker:

[image: Bare Minimum tracking marker]
**Bare Minimum:**
Some kind of point you can track the position of. Vulnerable to being lost due to noise. Can't track scale or rotation very well.

[image: better tracking marker]
**Better:**
A corner gives you more to track, and is less likely to get lost, but can disappear it the camera moves too much around the object, and you probably can't track it's scale.

[image: best tracking marker][image: best tracking marker]
**Best:**
Some kind of small pattern or grouping of features. This gives you something with high contrast that you can also keep track of the rotation and scaling of with the *Perspective* motion model. This should give you a more robust track and thus a better camera solution.

Comment: I read somewhere that one should not user the square ones (Best) because they throw the tracker off at different angles

Comment: This is true if you can't track perspective changes in the tracker, but blender now supports this.

Comment: What is the advantage of being able to track scale and rotation?

Comment: @AnsonSavage scale and rotation will improve tracking when features move towards the camera (or camera moves towards them) and if the camera rotates