# Motion tracking: object in my scene bonces around

Tags: tracking

For whatever reason when ever i insert an object into my scene, it bounces around. The markers I have placed, work perfectly, 0.183 solve error, but the object just bounces and moves when I render the video. The object it's self isn't moving, but for some reason the camera sees it that way or something like that. I don't really get it, I'm new to this whole motion tracking thing.

Comment: Please add more information about your scene and the shot you tracked. Is the shot you are tracking a stationary shot? How is the camera moving around the object in the original shot? It would help if you upload the shot in question to some hosting site on the internet and make the link available along with your blend file.

Comment: Okay here is my first render (I am using the white dots as markers):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4unNN6z7Qg&feature=youtu.be besides the weird glitch at the end, I don't understand why it slides around instead of staying in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents:

The "dots" on the scene are way to large, and you are using very few of them. With large trackers with no sharp edges (or [clearly distinct features](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/camera-tracking-markers)) is very likely that you are getting false positives and inaccurate tracking.

[image]

Also, the trackers are very close together, to get a proper 3D reconstruction you want the trackers to describe the space, so put them further apart and make them of a color that is clearly different than the background:

[image]

Keep in mind that to successfully reconstruct a scene blender needs some [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) information. Your camera hardly moves. You'll get a better solution if you walk a bit around the scene. Shifting perspective is the best way to estimate 3D space out of a video shot. In other words blender needs that the tracker points move at different rates to be able to estimate what is closer and what is further away.

**Please take some time and go through the suggestions listed on [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42332/1853). Hopefully they will help you achieve accurate motion tracking.**

Comment: Thanks I went back and made 20 smaller dots around the area, and it works so much better!