# Camera track drifts to the side

Tags: tracking

So, I have a video that I tracked in the movie clip editor. I put that data into a camera and added a cube, and the cube keeps drifting to the left. If this doesn't make sense, I can send you the .blend file. Click here to download the file.
[image]

Comment: what is the solve error?

Comment: please read link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/motion-tracking-my-model-zooms-in-or-out-or-is-sliding

Comment: without the video, the blend file is of limited use

Comment: Oh, sorry! I forgot that you need the video.

Comment: What I was thinking is that the floor was setup incorrectly.

Comment: please upload the Source Video.mp4 file to some hosting site and add the link to your question.

Comment: also read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49627/motion-tracking-object-in-my-scene-bonces-around/49642#49642