# Tracking all floor video

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I'm trying to track a video which is an all floor video. 
My camera barely moves.

When I try to do this I never get the result I need. Sometimes my camera in blender even goes upside down. Is there any easy way to do this or any tips?

[image: the footage i'm trying to track[1]]

Comment: Welcome to the site Mesirana! Sounds like you have a few bad tracks. Particularly in this case make sure your lens settings are correct. Your solve error is?  Does [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332) help? Otherwise please provide more information. Enjoy blender.SE!

Comment: Are you doing a simple tripod solve? This may not set up the camera correctly. The Motion Tracker really needs quite a bit of parallax change at some point to set up the Blender camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve error high with good track?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53435/solve-error-high-with-good-track)

Comment: Is there any displacement in the camera movement? If not, you need to solve as tripod. Motion tracking and reconstruction need some parallax. If the camera is stationary, blender cannot reconstruct the scene in 3d, and you should think of your scene as 2d tracking.