# Manual Assist for Motion Tracking

Tags: animation, camera, tracking, motion-capture

I recently made a video shot that I now need to motion track. However, due to motion blur at some points, as well as my limited experience and skills in this area, I am having some issues with setting it up to move right overall. There are some "blackspots" where I just can't get enough segments to track accurately. I am wondering if I can manually feed in approximate camera position and rotation for certain frames to help Blender solve motion track? Like give the rotations at different frames where I can make them out more or less certain and than let it calculate the rest. Or even better way would be - give it approximate movement of camera and let it sort out the details. Is this possible? And if it is, than - how?
Thanks!

Comment: In those frames where the tracker is slipping, you can place the tracker manually by selecting it, pressing **G**  and moving it using the arrow keys on the keyboard. Once you are done press Enter to confirm the change.

Comment: Read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71785/1853