# tracking operators ignore frame update

Tags: python, tracking, marker

I'm trying to make a script that adds motion trackers every n frames and tracks them but I can't get the `detect_features` and `track_markers` operators to run on a specified frame.

My approach is to jump the time cursor to the next "step" of n frames using any way I know to update the frame, namely:

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_current
bpy.context.scene.frame_set
bpy.ops.clip.change_frame
```

But for some reason, the tracking operators ignore all of these commands and always operate on the current frame instead (the one you're on when you press the Run button).
Here's a script that shows the problem. You can paste it in Blender’s text editor and run it, provided you have a Movie Clip Editor area with a clip open in it:

```py
import bpy
C = bpy.context
ctx = C.copy()
for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        ctx['area'] = area

for step in range(3) :
    currFrame = (step*20)+1
    C.scene.frame_current = currFrame
    C.scene.frame_set(currFrame)
    bpy.ops.clip.change_frame (ctx, frame = currFrame)
    bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
    bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(ctx, backwards = False, sequence = False)
```

Notice how after running it, all markers are tracked at the same frame and if you grab the currently selected markers with G, it will reveal the previously added markers underneath, at the same positions.

**EDIT:** I added a **[topic on blender devtalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/possible-bug-with-motion-tracker-api/17156)**.

**EDIT 2:** I also **[made an add-on](https://gitlab.com/ChameleonScales/step_tracker/)** with an interface for easier automated tracking (under development). Feel free to ask me anything about it.

Comment: There was a similar question here that ran into the exact same issue witht the frame not updating https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182322/tracking-script-in-python

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dupli. So I take it there is no solution as of yet.

Comment: **Duplicates are not bad!** I'm puzzled by the exact same question still. Hopefully this time someone can solve it.

Comment: Though I'm not sure that detecting features every frame will yield any better reconstruction...

Comment: Not every frame but every n frames. In my example it's every 20 frames. This is because the camera is on the road and the environment is constantly evolving, so the trackers have to be re-detected every now and then.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: brought this to devtalk : https://devtalk.blender.org/t/possible-bug-with-motion-tracker-api/17156

Comment: May not be the issue here. The recommended way to change frame is `scene.frame_set(frame)`

Comment: just tried and still not working, but thanks for trying

Comment: Found the solution!
I updated the question which is now an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was ok to have a post that directly provides a solution.
I reverted the OP back and will provide a complete answer on the other question.

Comment: @ChameleonScales thanks.

Comment: I see that you put your answer on the other question.  You can ignore my reopen, sorry.