# How to create a Blender camera to follow real camera in video?

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I have recently taken videos with a drone that I would like to edit in Blender. I would like to attach some objects that I have rendered in Blender into the video to simulate what the houses in the videos would look like with the objects on them.

A friend who used to use an older version of Blender said that it sounded like I needed to create a camera in Blender to follow the real camera path and then attach the objects from there.

Is it possible to do his suggestion? Or is there another way to go about this perhaps?

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm new to Blender and have only just been able to render my object the way I want it and I'm lost going forward with the videos.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3360/26640

Comment: You need to track your footage and do motion reconstruction using information from trackers. Not something anyone can teach you on a single answer. Do a search online for Sebastian Koenig's **Track Match Blend!**

Comment: Also spend some time to read through post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is called camera tracking, or matchmoving.  Read the related post that Scott Milner included in his comment, and I also recommend this video from BlenderGuru to help you get started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY

If you don't get your Blender camera to move exactly the same as your real camera, your Blender objects will never "sit" properly in your video.

EDIT: I replaced the video link; apparently the old link didn't work anymore - not surprising since I posted this 3 years ago!

Comment: This video is no longer available.

Comment: I updated the link. Cheers!

Comment: External links are always a problem because they might not be working after some time. Best practice is to provide full answers here so they stay available. Of course camera tracking is a much too complex field for a short answer. But if someone doesn't know that this technique is called _Camera Tracking_, this information might already help to find tutorials on this topic.